# Time Machine can't back up to an attached external USB drive

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, external-disk

Mac "A" (iMac, macOS 10.14) has an attached USB hard disk "EXT" (3TB, GUID, macOS Extended, Journaled). Mac "A" can use Time Machine successfully to back up to external drives shared from other current-OS Macs. Disk "EXT" is shared and other current-OS Macs can use Time Machine to successfully back up to it on the network.

BUT, Mac A can't use Time Machine successfully to back up to its own attached external hard disk "EXT". When preparing to encrypt and backup, this error dialog consistently appears:

> There was an error preparing the Time Machine backup disk "EXT". POSIX
>   reports: The operation couldn't be completed. Invalid argument.

I've tried reformatting the drive. Disk Utility shows no disk issues on "EXT". Finder and apps can access the disk without issue.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: I don't quite get why all these individual Time Machine drives (I assume you have multiple external HDs) on these Macs are so promiscuous. I can see using one Mac sharing a single TM drive on the network for providing TM backup volumes for the other Macs on the network, but I'm a bit mystified by the phrase "can Time Machine successfully." Could be more concise with the actual usage?

Comment: I have a lot of Macs, a lot of data, and I like to have Time Machine backups on at least two disks. "Time Machine successfully" just means that Time Machine is set up and completes its hourly backups as expected, with no errors (edited in the question for clarity).

Comment: So, does the drive in question work okay when connected directly to any of your other Macs? Also, can you access the drive okay manually from within Finder? Finally, are all Macs using the same version of macOS?

Comment: Yes, the drive is otherwise normal... any Mac can use it for non-Time-Machine read/write without issue, disk looks OK to Disk Utility, Finder, etc. All Macs using 10.14.current (this issue has been going on for a number of releases).

Comment: when you chose which drives to backup, you didn't accidentally choose the backup drive as well?

Comment: in time machine you select which drive to backup to and you select which drives to backup, Are all these correct?

Comment: The drives in the list of available drives all look normal, and I can back up to any network drives that are properly shared for Time Machine. re: excluding the external, I'll have to re-test that to verify, will take a little time.

Comment: Yes, I believe externals are automatically added to the exclude list in Options... and I just verified that "EXT" is in the excluded list just prior to trying again to make an encrypted backup. Time Machine will make an unencrypted backup, but an attempt at an encrypted backup to "EXT" yields the POSIX error. Other network Macs can make encrypted backups to "EXT".

Comment: Hmm, are all drives formatted the same?

Comment: The disk of interest is GUID, USB External Physical Volume, MacOS Extended (Journaled). macOS doesn't seem to want to do an encrypted Time Machine backup to this despite their support page recommendations: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202784

Comment: I erased the drive again, and was able to initiate an encrypted Time Machine backup. No explanation, I had erased before to no avail, and the format was identical: GUID, USB External Physical Volume, MacOS Extended (Journaled). So, problem solved(?) But no idea why.